# How to run Lua Scripts using OOLUA [C++]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, lua, oolua

How do you run lua scripts in OOLUA? I have a script named "script.lua" inside my C++ Project directory, and I tried doing this:

```
#include <OOLUA/oolua.h>

...

void Game::init() {
    OOLUA::Script vm;
    vm.run_file("Scripts/script.lua");
}
```

My script.lua looks like this:

```
print("Output From Lua Script!")
```

I have built and linked to the oolua.lib, and whenever I run my project I get these errors:

1>Game.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall OOLUA::Script::Script(void)" (??0Script@OOLUA@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Game::Game(void)" (??0Game@@QAE@XZ)
1>Game.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall OOLUA::Script::~Script(void)" (??1Script@OOLUA@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0Game@@QAE@XZ$1
1>Game.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall OOLUA::Script::run_file(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)" (?run_file@Script@OOLUA@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall Game::init(void)" (?init@Game@@AAEXXZ)

Am I doing it all completely wrong?

Comment: Your question isn't about running a scipt, so far you don't even come, it's about linking/building OOLua to/for your project. The error messages already tell you that references to OOLua functions are missing and your description doesn't explain how you build and link.

Comment: I built OOLua with premake5, and then built the static library by opening the vs2013 project. I built fine without any errors. I also built Lua 5.3. I have set my Library Directory to be "$(SolutionDir)deps/lib", where all my libraries are located, and linked to it in Linker ->Input -> Additional Dependencies. This has worked for all my other libraries, so I don't see why it doesn't work for oolua.